# Append text to a file with pattern matched name in bash

Tags: linux, bash, append, pattern-matching, aix

I am trying to add a line to a specific file which matches a pattern in its name.

e.g. I am trying to append text `STATUS PASSED` to a file whose name contains `2018_09_26_04_51_30`.

```
date="2018_09_26_04_51_30"
echo "STATUS PASSED" >> "/test_dir/*$date*.txt"
```

Above said commands are creating new file named `*2018_09_26_04_51_30*.txt` which is not serving my purpose!

Let's assume that there are several other files with `*.txt` extension, but none of these files contains `$date` in their names.

The `test_dir` directory contains:

```
test1-2018_09_26_04_50_48.txt
test2-2018_09_26_04_50_56.txt
test3-2018_09_26_04_51_03.txt
test3-2018_09_26_04_51_30_51S.txt
```

So, here file `test3-2018_09_26_04_51_30_51S.txt` is unique.

P.S. I have to execute this script in both Linux and AIX.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: aix is not linux, why you have both tags?

Comment: @Kent As I have written in my original question, I need a command which will be executable in both Linux and AIX platforms!

Answer (score -1):

Try like this,

```
date="2018_09_26_04_51_30"
#cd /test_dir
echo "STATUS PASSED" >> $(ls /test_dir/*$date*.txt)
```

Comment: You don't need command substitution and `ls`, and you should still quote `$date`: `>> /test_dir/*"$date"*.txt` should do.

Comment: That will not run in redirection

Comment: `touch xABCx; v=ABC; echo 'BLAH' >> *"$v"*; cat xABCx` works, if the glob expands to just one file, otherwise you get "ambiguous redirect", but you get that also with the `ls $(...)` solution.